# Is it possible to assign two different selectors to keyboard return and keyboard hide keys in ipad using objective c

Tags: ios, ipad

i want to call a function when keyboard return key is pressed and i want to call another function when keyboard hide key is pressed in iPad .. so i need to check whether return key is pressed or hide key is pressed..

Comment: Show your existing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check by using UITextField delegates methods for ex...

```
//Managing Editing

– textFieldShouldBeginEditing:
– textFieldDidBeginEditing:
– textFieldShouldEndEditing:
– textFieldDidEndEditing:

//Editing the Text Field’s Text

– textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:
– textFieldShouldClear:
– textFieldShouldReturn:
```

– textFieldShouldReturn: method calls only when user clicks return button in keyboard. It will not call when user click on hide key...by this u can check.

**Update**

use keyboard notifications:

```
- UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
- UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
- UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
- UIKeyboardDidHideNotification
- UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification
- UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification
```

for "UIKeyboardWillHideNotification". So just implemented:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(KeyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, but is there any specific function called when hide key button is pressed ..

Comment: Hi @kalai, check my update...hope it may help